# Simplest way to uninstall all PIP packages outside of venv on Windows

Tags: python, powershell, pip

I have seen some techniques to uninstall all pip packages using lists. Most answers to questions appear to be linux based. Any recommendations as I had pip installed quite a few libraries on an old windows laptop outside of a venv a few years back.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run this in command prompt(no adminstrator priveleges) prompt:

```
pip freeze > packagelist.txt
pip uninstall -r .\packagelist.txt -y
```

Another more programmatic way would be :

```
$packages = pip freeze 

foreach ($package in $packages ){
pip uninstall $package -y

}
```

both work the same but the first example creates a .txt file, you may want to delete that

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

Comment: @TD you mean you got errors related to xargs when you ran this command?

Comment: yes, does xargs come standard, or is something necessary to install prior to running